# how to filter mongodb data in powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, filter

I am trying to recover mongo data from a Mongo database using a PowerShell script. But the difficulty is not to recover the data, because it works. The real difficulty is to filter the data that I recover by taking those which interest me.

For that i allready try 2 script. they do the same things, recover all of the data butt they not do the filter.

Here is the first script I Try :

```
Import-Module Mdbc;

function New-MongoExport {
  param (
    # Your Server's URL
    [string]
    $Url = "mongodb://sercentos1:27017",
    # Database to connect to
    [string]
    $Db = "referentiel-planning",
    # Collection Name
    [string] 
    $CollectionName = "planning",
    # Where do we want to put that information
    [string] 
    $Path = "C:\Users\jhism\Documents\MISSIONS\merge2Mongodb\merge2MongodbInPowershell\collections\$collectionName.json",
    # Default Limit
    [int16] 
    $Limit = 1
  )
  # Remove the file if it exists
  Remove-Item $Path -ErrorAction Continue;
  # Connect and count
  Connect-Mdbc $Url $Db $CollectionName;
  $count = Get-MdbcData -Count;
  $data = Get-MdbcData (New-MdbcQuery -And (New-MdbcQuery isTemplate -EQ false), (New-MdbcQuery tenant -EQ spo2));
  Write-Host $data
  $dataCount = $data.Count 
  Write-Host $dataCount


  # Do some fancy output
  Write-Host "Exporting $($count) records" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkCyan;
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i += $Limit) {
    # You don't actually need to paginate
    # The module uses the mongo driver so it's quite fast
    # But anyways it reads like `Skip $i items and take the first $Limit items then, export those`
    Get-MdbcData -Skip $i -First $Limit | Export-MdbcData $Path -Append;
  }
   Write-Host "File Written: $Path" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green;

}

New-MongoExport
```

The second script than i try is not to much different but here it is :

```
Import-Module Mdbc;


function New-MongoExport {
  param (
    # Your Server's URL
    [string]
    $Url = "mongodb://sercentos1:27017",
    # Database to connect to
    [string]
    $Db = "referentiel-planning",
    # Collection Name
    [string] 
    $CollectionName = "planning",
    # Where do we want to put that information
    [string] 
    $Path = "C:\Users\jhism\Documents\MISSIONS\merge2Mongodb\merge2MongodbInPowershell\collections\$collectionName.json",
    # Default Limit
    [int16] 
    $Limit = 1
  )
  # Remove the file if it exists
  Remove-Item $Path -ErrorAction Continue;
  # Connect and count
  Connect-Mdbc $Url $Db $CollectionName;

 $data =  @{isTemplate = "false"}, @{tenant = "spo2"} | Get-MdbcData

  <#$data = Get-MdbcData (New-MdbcQuery -And (New-MdbcQuery isTemplate -EQ false), (New-MdbcQuery tenant -EQ spo2))
  Write-Host $data#>
  $count = $data.count
  Write-Host $count


  # Do some fancy output
  Write-Host "Exporting $($count) records" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkCyan;
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i += $Limit) {
    # You don't actually need to paginate
    # The module uses the mongo driver so it's quite fast
    # But anyways it reads like `Skip $i items and take the first $Limit items then, export those`
    Get-MdbcData -Skip $i -First $Limit | Export-MdbcData $Path -Append;
  }
       Write-Host "File Written: $Path" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green;

}

New-MongoExport
```

here where i found some help : https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc 
and 
https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/blob/master/Tests/Get-MdbcData.test.ps1

Despite all this I do not have the desired result.

Here is a little exemple of the result i have (*this is a collection than we'll name : **col1***). As you can see, the filter doesn't work, I have all of the data :

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("7c74e7ca4325558"), 
 "isTemplate" : false,
 "tenant" : "spo1"
},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("7a22e7ca444478"), 
 "isTemplate" : true,
 "tenant" : "spo"
},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("3d55e7ca432798"), 
 "isTemplate" : false,
 "tenant" : "spo2"
},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b74e7ca432001"), 
 "isTemplate" : true,
 "tenant" : "spo2"
}
```

Here is another little exemple of the desired result :

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("3d55e7ca432798"), 
 "isTemplate" : false,
 "tenant" : "spo2"
}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: "I do not have the desired result.", well what results _are you getting_ and which results are _desired_? We can neither see your screen nor read your mind :)

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to tell you about that. I m gonna edit the post.